# How to report from a BroadcastReceiver back to a Service in Android?

Tags: android

I have a service that is running and that is interested in being notified if packages are installed, removed, or updated.

I understand that I should use a Broadcast receiver, but it clearly says in [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that...

> you may not show a dialog or bind to a
>   service from within a
>   BroadcastReceiver

So my question is - How can I inform the service that such broadcasts have been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to it but nothing prohibits to call the service via a an intent :

```
context.startService( <your intent with a name that match the filter of your service> );
```

Then put your data within extras of this intent, as usual.

Another option could be AIDL but I didn't explore that yet.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the text you quoted...

> In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from within a BroadcastReceiver. For the former, you should instead use the NotificationManager API. **For the latter, you can use Context.startService() to send a command to the service.**

From the [Context.startService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) docs...

> If this service is not already running, it will be instantiated and started (creating a process for it if needed); **if it is running then it remains running**.

In other words, a win/win situation as calling `startService()` on a service which is already running won't have an adverse effect.